Is there a map from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]^n$ that preserves distances between points?
I'm trying to figure out if one could construct a surjective map $f:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]^n$ ($n>2$) such that, given any point $\vec{x}\in[0,1]^2$, all points belonging to a circumference of radius $r>0$ centered in $(x,y)$ map to points in a $n$-dimensional hypersphere, all equidistant from $\vec{y}=f(\vec{x})$.
It's clear to me that for a map from the unit segment to a $n$-dimensional unit hypercube, $[0,1]\to[0,1]^n$, this cannot be possible, because given any point $x\in[0,1]$, I can only have at most 2 points at $x\pm r$, so obviously one cannot map a finite set of points to an uncountable infinite set, and so distances won't be preserved.
However I'm not sure if the same can be said for a map such as $f$. Is there any result that ensures such a map cannot exist? If not, what does $f$ looks like?

No, such map does not exist. The argument for $[0,1]$ can be generalized. Pick (a bit cleverly) two points $x,y\in[0,1]^2$ and an $r>d(x,y)$. There are at most two points $p$ in $[0,1]^2$ such that $d(p,x)=d(p,y)=r$, but there could be infinitely many such points in $[0,1]^n$. Similarly, by picking more points, you can show no such map exists $[0,1]^m \to [0,1]^n$ when $m<n$.

That's a very good point, I think that now I'm convinced such maps cannot exist. Thank you
